# Laravel 5 LEFT JOIN issue with id's

Tags: php, laravel, join, left-join

I have an issue with LEFT JOIN. I do not want to use eloquent relations because I want to keep my models folder clean. I have an appointments application in which I am using "labels" and "statuses". I want to be able to filter my view based on the labels and statuses. The issue with the LEFT JOIN is that when I want to click on my edit link, it uses the "id" field from my "appointments_statuses" table, instead of the "appointments" table. Below is the relevant code:

My controller:

```
$appointments = $query->orderBy('appointment', 'asc')
->leftJoin('appointments_labels','appointments_labels.id','=','appointments.label_id')
->leftJoin('appointments_statuses','appointments_statuses.id','=','appointments.status_id')
->get();
```

My view:

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
    <a href="#">{{ $appointment->id }}</a> // Problem here, it uses the "status_id" field from the "appointments" table instead of the "id" field
@endforeach
```

My database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`appointment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`start` datetime NOT NULL,
`end` datetime NOT NULL,
`label_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments_labels` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments_statuses` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`flag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because your query collects ALL the fields of the 3 tables, so the columns with the same name get overwritten.
Simply use a `select()` on what fields you want (which is a good practice, anyway):

```
$appointments = $query->orderBy('appointment', 'asc')
->leftJoin('appointments_labels','appointments_labels.id','=','appointments.label_id')
->leftJoin('appointments_statuses','appointments_statuses.id','=','appointments.status_id')
->select('appointments.id', 'appointments.name', '........', 'appointments_statuses.name', 'appointments_labels.name')
->get();
```

**NB:** I'm guessing the fields you want from the main and the joined tables, but you get the idea :)
**NB2:** You can also pass an `array` of values to the `select()` method:

```
->select(['appointments.id', 'appointments.name', ....])
```

Comment: Awesome, yeah good practice, it's the whole reason I am building this application. Thanks, I am sure I will get this to work now, so I accepted the answer :)